# gdalinfo for Modis layer "NDVI"

Tags: gdal, modis, gdalinfo

I am trying the following command to get info on the NDVI MODIS layer stored in HDF file. I always receive an error. the command and error as below: `gdalinfo HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:MYD13A2.A2015297.h16v05.005.2015314081208.hdf:MODIS_Grid_16DAY_1km_VI:1 km 16 days NDV`

error: 
FAILURE: Too many command options.

Comment: I don't believe you are using the correct command (or the correct input).  See http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html  gdalinfo is looking for a file

Comment: @MaryBeth in the case of HDF containers you can adress the subdatasets directly by using their full name (of which the filename of the parent file is just a part).

Comment: Thanks! I see now that wrapping in quotes would be fine--the parameters just didn't look right to me  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to adress a subdataset inside a HDF container directly. There are two ways you can do that with `gdalinfo`:

1. Put the complete name of the subdataset in parantheses `gdalinfo " HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:MYD13A2.A2015297.h16v05.005.2015314081208.hdf:MODIS_Grid_16DAY_1km_VI:1 km 16 days NDVI"`
2. Use the subdataset option `gdalinfo -sd 1 MYD13A2.A2015297.h16v05.005.2015314081208.hdf`

Comment: I am still new, Would you please add more clarification on -sd 2. I need to understand the meaning

Comment: See @Daniels s answer for further clarification. `-sd` stands for *subdataset* and tells gdal which subdataset to select when more than 1 is present.

Answer (score 0):

The sd flag will retrieve a subdataset that's inside the file (if present). It's explained in [gdalinfo man page](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html).

The number after the sd flag will be the subdataset number. But be carefull. For MOD13Q1, **NDVI is subdataset 1**. **Subdataset 2 is EVI**. And I believe the same order applies to MYD13A2

You can see the subdataset numbers by issuing gdalinfo on the hdf file, without the sd flag.